# How to generate non-blanks between words?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

In an otherwise-vanilla latex doc, I have a long list of strings that I need separated by `<space> <cdot> <space>`.  The output needs to look like:

```
Lorem <cdot> ipsum  <cdot> dolor <cdot> sit
amet <cdot> consectetuer <cdot> adipiscing
```

It's trivial to write a `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\mbox{#1} \ $\cdotp$\ \ }`, but that approach is unaware of TeX's newlines, and produces output like

```
Lorem <cdot> ipsum  <cdot> dolor <cdot> sit
<cdot> amet <cdot> consectetuer <cdot>  <<<--- <cdot> at beginning and end of line
adipiscing
```

If it makes any difference, the document is `\raggedright` throughout.

This issue feels like it involves TeX's line and paragraph breaking, which, for me, is in the Land Of Monsters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  if you don't want a `\cdot` at the beginning of a line, but don't mind one at the end, you can use this string: `~$\cdotp$\ ` (the `~` represents an unbreakable space, so the `\cdot` will never go by itself to the beginning of the next line).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with a macro or an environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\changespace}{ O{\nobreakspace$\cdot$~} +m }
 {
  \cdotp_changespace:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_cdotp_phrases_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cdotp_changespace:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cdotp_phrases_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_cdotp_phrases_tl { ~ } { #1 }
  \tl_use:N \l_cdotp_phrases_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cdotp_changespace:nn { nV }

\NewEnviron{spaces}[1][\nobreakspace$\cdot$~]
 {
  \cdotp_changespace:nV { #1 } \BODY
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\changespace{Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.

Something else  with   multiple  spaces.}

\changespace[~X ]{Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.

Something else  with   multiple  spaces.}

\begin{spaces}
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.

Something else  with   multiple  spaces.
\end{spaces}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument is for changing the separator. Recall that between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` a space must be specified as `~`.

[image]

---

If you want that the dot disappears at line breaks and at end of paragraphs, with raggedright setting, here's an adaptation of a [trick by Marcin Woliński](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2007p/marcin-wolinski/bachotex2007-marcin-wolinski-pearl1.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ,textcomp}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_cdotp_phrases_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cdotp_changespace:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cdotp_phrases_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_cdotp_phrases_tl { ~ } { \disappearingdot }
  \tl_use:N \l_cdotp_phrases_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cdotp_changespace:n { V }

\NewEnviron{spaces}
 {\raggedright\def\par{\unskip\unskip\endgraf}
  \cdotp_changespace:V \BODY
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\disappearingdot}{%
 \hskip 1pt plus 2pt
 \cleaders\hbox to.2em{\hss$\cdot$\hss}\hskip.2em\relax
 \hskip 1pt plus 2pt\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{spaces}
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.

Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.
Lorem ipsum  dolor sit
amet consectetuer adipiscing.

\end{spaces}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**First version:**

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\catcode`\ =13%
\def {~$\cdot$\ }%
\def\Ala{Ala ma kota. }
\def\Alax{\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala}

\Alax

\catcode`\ =10%

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Revised, after your clarification:** (Just now I can see, how beautiful is your question. It evokes some aspects of depth of paragraph breaking algorithm. Hence the solution is one-line and vanilla TeX.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\def\1{\discretionary{}{}{\mbox{\ $\cdot$\ }}}%
\def\Ala{Ala\1ma\1kota.\1}
\def\Alax{\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala\Ala}

We put\1 breaks only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1only here\1and here\1

\Alax

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not that it is necessarily a problem for the user, but your approach requires that the `\def\Ala{...}` occur after the `\catcode` is changed, since the catcode is applied at the time of `\def`.  That might be a problem is the user wanted to operate on a string defined outside the scope of his routine.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, `\Alax` produces only some text which can be written manually, as well.

Comment: Thanks to Przemysław.  Let me clarify the goal -- I want the <cdot> as token separators within a line, but never to appear at the beginning or end of a line.  The \catcode idea is great but addresses a slightly different problem.  

Also, some of the tokens may have nonbreaking spaces, and the output should look like:

    abc<nbsp>def <cdot> ghi 

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @cdotp So it means that you put your <cdot> manually, not at every space? Or every space should be `\ \cdot \ ` instead of those at the begining or end of line, beacause they should vanish?

Comment: My point @PrzemysławScherwentke is that, if the user's code is inside a style package, he may have no control over what string is passed for processing.  If the string to be processed were defined prior to the catcode change, your method would break. (To see this in your code, move the `\catcode` change down 4 lines, after the `\def\Alax{...}` but before the `\Alax`)

Comment: @Przemysław -- That's right, the <cdot> goes between each logical entry.  I imagine the solution will involve something like:

\foo{str one}  \foo{another token string} \foo{ok} ... and generate output like:
str one <cdot> another token string <cdot> ok \n

In the desired solution, there will never be a <cdot> at the beginning or end of a line.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- Perfect!!  \discretionary was the magic I needed.

Answer (score 5):

[EDITED to show that the approach can work on predefined strings].

The stringstrings package is intended to operate on (duh!) strings.  Its `\convertchar` routine takes the string given in the first argument and looks for occurances of the character given by the second argument.  When it finds them, it replaces them with the third argument.  While many common character macros are understood (i.e., digestible) by stringstrings, it is generally not able to digest macros in the strings.  That can be circumvented in a "limited" way with the `\encodetoken` feature of the package which, in essence, makes the macro known to the package (the limitation is on the number of "unknown" macros that the package can simultaneously process).

Note: stringstrings routines will differentiate between hardspace and softspace, as demonstrated in the UPDATED example below, where hardspaces are used between words 1, 2 and 3 of the paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\makeatletter
\def\@MAXSTRINGSIZE{4096}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\def\x{%
Lorem~ipsum~dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna.  Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.  Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.  Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.}

\encodetoken{\cdot}
\convertchar{\x}{ }{~$\cdot$~}
\decodetoken{\cdot}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a few words about what in the world is going on here?